# use state instead of outside class variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use my data which keep in my state instead of the outside class variable (I mean languages if u look at the code below)

In the getSuggestion I change `languages.filter(lang....`  to `this.state.myState.filter(lang...` but it's not work

It seem like `this.state.myState` can't be reach

The error appear at the `line  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : this.state.myState.filter(lang =>` in the getSuggestion

```
 import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

// Imagine you have a list of languages that you'd like to autosuggest.
const languages = [
  {
    name: 'C',
    year: 1972
  },
  {
    name: 'Elm',
    year: 2012
  },

];

// Teach Autosuggest how to calculate suggestions for any given input value.
const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;

  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : languages.filter(lang =>
    lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
  );
};

// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion. Teach Autosuggest how to calculate the
// input value for every given suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;

// Use your imagination to render suggestions.
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
  <div>
    {suggestion.name}
  </div>
);

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Autosuggest is a controlled component.
    // This means that you need to provide an input value
    // and an onChange handler that updates this value (see below).
    // Suggestions also need to be provided to the Autosuggest,
    // and they are initially empty because the Autosuggest is closed.
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
      myState: [
  {
    name: 'C',
    year: 1972
  },
  {
    name: 'Elm',
    year: 2012
  }
] ,

    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
  // You already implemented this logic above, so just use it.
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Type a programming language',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    // Finally, render it!
    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: **What's the error?**

Comment: Your functions `getSuggestions`, `getSuggestionValue` and `renderSuggestions` are all outside the scope the React component and hence they don't have access to state, move them within the class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to access `this` in a function outside of your class, so your `this` will not be defined in `getSuggestions`.

If `getSuggestions` needs to be defined outside of your class, you'll need to make two changes:

1. define `getSuggestions` as a normal `function` as opposed to an arrow function so that we can set `getSuggestions`'s `this` object manually.
2. Use `Function.prototype.call()` to call `getSuggestions` with a specified value for `this`.

I wrote up a few examples to show my point. First, notice in the example below, where `getSuggestions` is an arrow function and it is called by method of `Example` class:

```js
const getThis = () => {

    console.log(this === window || this === undefined); // this is coerced to window or undefined (Strict Mode)
};

class Example {

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested() {

        console.log(this); // prints correctly 
        getThis();
    };
}

var x = new Example();

x.onSuggestionsFetchRequested(); // prints true once
```

In `getThis`, the `this` object will either be `Window` or `undefined` (Strict Mode).

To make the setup above work, we make the two changes proposed above:

```js
const getThis = function() { // change #1: use function() {} vs. () => {}

    console.log(this); // correct value for this
};

class Example {

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested() {

        console.log(this);
        getThis.call(this); // change #2: use call()
    };
    
    // NOTE: in your code, define onSuggestionsFetchRequested using arrow function syntax like so:
    // onSuggestionsFetchRequested = () => { ... }; 
    // I did not use the arrow syntax above so that this example would run in the browser, 
    // but you would need to in order to use onSuggestionsFetchRequested in callbacks. 
}

var x = new Example();

x.onSuggestionsFetchRequested();
```

**Note:** I made a small modification above to make the snippet run in the browser. Namely, I defined `onSuggestionsFetchRequest` as a class method as opposed to a class property (using arrow function syntax) as you have in your code. For your use case, you'll want to keep `onSuggestionsFetchRequest` defined using arrow function syntax so that it can be used in callbacks.